# Why do I get this error in React.js + GraphQL: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, graphql, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to setup a React/GraphQL App. This is my code. I double checked my imports/package.json but I keep getting a syntax error ("Unexpected token") from webpack on the 10th line and I just can't figure out why.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

const client = new ApolloClient({});

const Root = () => {
  return(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}> 
        <div>Lyrical</div>  
      </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: Are you sure you configured WebPack to compile JSX?

Comment: So, if I had, this code should work? I am actually following along this tutorial and cloned a github repository recommended for it. It is supposed to have the initial setup but maybe it is outdated or so. I'll double check. Thanks @SLaks !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a .babelrc file in your main directory (parallel to webpack.config.js) that contains

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

I'm not sure why ApolloProvider specifically needs this, but adding this simple line fixed it for me.